# Knapsack logic sorting by max value and duration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, knapsack-problem

i had encountered a bottleneck on my Knapsack logic.

i had an array of songs(60 mins) and would like to limit the time to 15 mins(900 secs)

i had sorted the songs in 8 diff moods would like to have at least one songs within the limits however its not necessary that all 8 moods needs to be inside the limits subjects to filters

i had `sortSongsWithWeight` sorting them with the first song with a value of 1

and `processingWeightIndex` to find the max possible songs to fit within 15 mins however the function did not take into account of the value. I am not very sure where i did wrong.

appreciated any comments and pointer thanks!

```
-(NSMutableArray*)sortSongsWithWeight:(NSMutableArray*)plArray
{
    NSMutableArray *weightArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    __block int mood = 0;
    __block int value = 1;

    [plArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Song* songObj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        if (![songObj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) // check for null
        {
            WeightObject *obj = [[WeightObject alloc]init];

            if ([songObj.mood intValue] == mood)
            {
                obj.songIndex = @(idx); //index of array of songs
                obj.songDurationORweight = songObj.playbackDuration; //song duration
                obj.mood = songObj.mood;
                obj.songName = songObj.songName;
                obj.Value = @(value);
            }
            else if([songObj.mood intValue] <= mood || [songObj.mood intValue] >= mood )
            {
                obj.songIndex = @(idx); //index of array of songs
                obj.songDurationORweight = songObj.playbackDuration; //song duration
                obj.mood = songObj.mood;
                obj.songName = songObj.songName;
                obj.Value = @(1);
                value = 0;
                mood = [songObj.mood intValue];
            }
            [weightArray addObject:obj];
            NSLog(@"obj index %@ songName %@ songDurations %@ and Value %@ Mood %@ ",obj.songIndex,obj.songName, obj.songDurationORweight,obj.Value,obj.mood);
        }
    }];
    return  weightArray;
}


#define max(a,b) (a > b ? a : b)

int matrix[200][200] = {0}; //40000 songs 200 * 200
int picks[200][200] = {0};

//main chunk of code for Knapsack logic
-(int)processingWeightIndex:(int)index withWeightObj:(NSMutableArray*)weightArray andLimits:(int)limits
{
    //     index = index of the item that need to decide to pick or not, start with the last inde of the array to first
    //     limits = size of durations, reduced when songs picked
    //     weightArray = array with the weight obj of all items

    int take,dontTake;
    take = dontTake = 0;

    WeightObject *obj = weightArray[index];

    if (matrix[index][limits]!=0)
    return matrix[index][limits];

    if (index==0)
    {
        if ([obj.songDurationORweight intValue] <= limits) //205 <= 900
        {
            picks[index][limits] = 1; // picked equal true index is [0][900]
           // matrix[index][limits] = [obj.songDurationORweight intValue]; // martix value @ index [0][900]
             matrix[index][limits] = [obj.songDurationORweight intValue]; // martix value @ index [0][900]
            //return [obj.songDurationORweight intValue];
            return [obj.songDurationORweight intValue];
        }
        else
        {
            picks[index][limits] = -1; // not picked
            matrix[index][limits] = 0; // value equal 0
            return 0;
        }
    }

    if ([obj.songDurationORweight intValue] <= limits) //205 <= 900
    {
        take = [obj.songDurationORweight intValue] + [self processingWeightIndex:index - 1 withWeightObj:weightArray andLimits:limits - [obj.songDurationORweight intValue]];
        //take = [obj.Value intValue] + [self processingWeightIndex:index - 1 withWeightObj:weightArray andLimits:limits - [obj.songDurationORweight intValue]];
    }

    dontTake = [self processingWeightIndex:index - 1 withWeightObj:weightArray andLimits:limits];
    matrix[index][limits] = max (take, dontTake);

    if (take > dontTake)
    picks[index][limits] = 1;
    else
    picks[index][limits] = -1;

    NSLog(@"picks[%d][%d] picks %d  %d",index,limits,picks[index][limits],matrix[index][limits]);
    return matrix[index][limits];
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if it causes the problem, but `matrix[200][200]`, `picks[200][200]` looks pretty suspicious, it should be `...[200][901]`, where 200 is number of songs and 901 is knapsack capacity + 1.

Comment: what does this mean:  "i had an array of songs(60 mins)".  is the TOTAL 60 minutes? or what?

Answer (score 0):

In the else block, you set the value to 0:

```
            value = 0;
```

Then when the next element will hit the if block, it will assign the song a 0 value, and as a result, all the songs that match from here on will be value = 0, while all the songs that do not match will be value = 1. Consequently, your knapsack will not take into account the values except for any songs that had matched the mood before the first song that did not match the mood.

There are probably other issues with the code but since your code that calls these two methods is not available, it is hard to figure out what's going on esp. whether the processingWeightIndex method is doing what it's supposed to do.